# Using a For loop with an array and addEventListener

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have this map I'm creating in Flash. You click on a state, then you can click on an icon to view a tooltip/popup of some information. What I was trying to do was instead of creating new functions and event listeners for every different icon is to use a for loop...but it's not going so well. I haven't touched AS in a long time so bear with me :)

```
var ToolTipMC = map.toolTip;
ToolTipMC.alpha = 0;
var places:Array = new Array();

places = [ "map.paulsens", "map.plutonic", "map.jundee", "map.wiluna", "map.darlot", "map.lawers", "map.gwaliaDeeps", "map.sunriseDam", "map.marvelLoch" ];

function enableToolTips( event:MouseEvent ):void {
    ToolTipMC.x = places[ i ].x + 10;
    ToolTipMC.y = places[ i ].y - ( ToolTipMC.height - 9 );
    Tweener.addTween( ToolTipMC, { y: ToolTipMC.y + 5, alpha: 1, transition: "easeInOutExpo", time: 0.3 } );
    ToolTipMC.toolTipTextField.text = "It worked!";
    trace( "Mouse Over" );
}

function disableToolTips( event:MouseEvent ):void {
    Tweener.addTween( ToolTipMC, { alpha: 0, transition: "easeInOutExpo", time: 0.3 } );
    trace( "Mouse Out" );
}

for( var i:uint = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
    places[ i ].addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, enableToolTips );
    places[ i ].addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, disableToolTips );
}
```

The items in the array are instance names and I'm using the Tweener class(es).

The following throws an Output error of

> TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function

and is stopping at the

```
places[ i ].addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, enableToolTips );
```

So from this I can gather that it's having problems parsing the array values through to the event listener, but that's as far as I got :). Could anyone please help me with my dilema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few things that might be causing the problem:

1. **Places are "strings", not IEventDispatchers**
2. Not sure you can run a for-loop outside of a function, try wrapping it in a function.

Here's what it might look like.

```
function addListeners():void {
    for( var i:uint = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
        (places[ i ] as IEventDispatcher).addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, enableToolTips );
        (places[ i ] as IEventDispatcher).addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, disableToolTips );
    }
}
```

You'd have to convert `places` to an Array of IEventDispatchers, maybe map items or whatever you're doing, some DisplayObject.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Okay well this threw an error for the enableToolTips() function because the places[i] has no 'i' being referenced inside the function. So I placed another for loop (using i, should I use another var?) in there and no errors. But the tooltip movieclip is not showing up when I am hovering over the icons. Any ideas? Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: This is the correct answer - see my answer for help with your subsequent error...

Answer (score 1):

Following on from viatropos's answer - I assume you want to access the "place" with your tooltip that sent the event? You can do this using `event.target`:

```
function enableToolTips( event:MouseEvent ):void {
    var place:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
    ToolTipMC.x = place.x + 10;
    ToolTipMC.y = place.y - ( ToolTipMC.height - 9 );

    //the rest of your function...
}
```

(I'm also guessing that your "places" are movieclips placed on the stage - hence the cast to `DisplayObject`)

Comment: Thanks for your help Reuben :-). Okay well your above code throws no problems apart from the appearance that the tooltip movieclip is still not showing up. Is the enableToolTips() function even activating? The trace doesn't even fire. I removed the x and y positioning just to see if it was being moved off-screen but still nothing.

Yes my places[] array items are instance names of movieclips on the stage. I have each icon movieclip inside the 'map' movieclip.

Comment: Your code probably still isn't adding listeners correctly, I'm not sure if you can just convert the Strings to IEventDispatchers and have this work - If your places are on the stage in a map movieclip you don't have to reference them via strings, try replacing places = [ "map.paulsens", "map.plutonic",... with places = [map.paulsens, map.plutonic,... this way you will have a direct reference to the MovieClip that you can add event listeners to.